# An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float''

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
def get_geohash(Latitude,Longitude):
    geohash = gh.encode(Latitude, Longitude, precision=5)
    return geohash

geohash_udf = udf(lambda x,y:get_geohash(x,y),StringType())

hotels = hotels.withColumn('geohash', geohash_udf(col('Latitude'),col('Longitude')))
```

i was getting the below error
An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'',

Comment: what is geohash? could you format the code snippet (use the code formatter, usually a {} sign in the editor box), include all import statements and also paste the entire error stacktrace to help understand the entire error?

Comment: What does your original dataframe look like? Can you do a hotels.show(5) and a hotels.printSchema() and paste the output in the question?

Comment: The exception is clear right? You are comparing a string with a float. It could be that you have a numerical column that is stored as a string (that is the default type for spark), or it could be that you have a value that is a string instead of a number.